# Use tabs for indentation in Python mode

Tags: emacs, python, indentation

I am using Emacs for Python developement. My team is using <kbd>Tab</kbd> indentation, so I must do the same. The problem is that I can't figure out how to make python-mode use tabs instead of spaces. I want Emacs to automatically indent my line to the correct level when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
```

Comment: I'm a spoiled vim user, so I really don't know. What does the '-character do/mean? I find it rather odd to see an odd number of those in one statement ...

Comment: @user1129682 quotation, see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html

Comment: @user1129682, emacs is mostly written in LISP, and the above is a LISP statement adding a function to `python-mode-hook`, a list of functions to run when starting to edit Python code. What the apostrophe does is to tell LISP that `python-mode-hook` is the variable to modify, not its name.